# using a non-blocking socket connection in C

Tags: c, sockets

I'm changing a socket connection in a script to a non-blocking connection. In a tutorial I found the lines:

```
x=fcntl(s,F_GETFL,0);              // Get socket flags
fcntl(s,F_SETFL,x | O_NONBLOCK);   // Add non-blocking flag
```

So I added them after I create my socket and before the connect statement. And it's no longer blocking :) but it also doesn't connect. I'm not getting any errors, the connect is just returning -1. If I comment these lines out it connects.

What else do I need to add to get a non-blocking connection to connect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check return value of [`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html) - you should be getting `-1`, and `EINPROGRESS` in [`errno(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html). Then add socket file descriptor to a poll set, and wait on it with [`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) or [`poll(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html).

This way you can have multiple connection attempts going on at the same time (that's how e.g. browsers do it) and be able to have tighter timeouts.

Answer (score 4):

[connect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) will probably immediately return a EINPROGRESS error.  Read up on use of [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select).

Note that you'll probably want to wrap your call to select in the [TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Interrupted-Primitives.html) macro.

Comment: Hmm, what's the point here? How is it different from *blocking* `connect`?

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov Fair point, I've edited my answer to remove the code snippet as potentially misleading and emphasise use of TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY